# julia MethodError: no method matching length(::WinRPM.RPMVersionNumber)

Tags: windows, graphics, gtk, julia

got this error running Julia v1.0.0 x64 upon win10 x64.
Because of this I am unable to use any graphical libraries.

```
Error: Error building Gtk:
│ [ Info: Multiple package candidates found for mingw64(libjpeg-8.dll), picking newest.
│ ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching length(::WinRPM.RPMVersionNumber)
│ Closest candidates are:
│ length(!Matched::Core.SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:571
│ length(!Matched::Base.MethodList) at reflection.jl:728
│ length(!Matched::Core.MethodTable) at reflection.jl:802
```

Comment: Don't worry, you can do Julia graphics on Windows.  Have you tried the [Plot Installation](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/install/) instructions?  ... or some of the tutorial there?

Answer (score 0):

It not working currently. All you can do is to vote on these GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Gtk.jl/issues/369
- https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/WinRPM.jl/issues/163

Good plotting alternative is `Plots.jl` with GR backend or `PyPlot.jl` (`PyPlot.jl` can be also used with `Plots.jl` for standarized API).